# What characters are allowed in event names?

Tags: solidity, events

I'm having trouble locating any documentation on which characters are allowed in Ethereum event names. For example, can I put cyrillic characters in them? Can I put emojis? What is allowed and disallowed in an Ethereum event name?

I'm asking in general terms, not just Solidity.

Comment: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/grammar.html#a4.SolidityParser.eventDefinition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An identifier in solidity has to start with a letter, a dollar-sign or an underscore and may additionally contain numbers after the first symbol.

from https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/grammar.html#a4.SolidityLexer.Identifier

Answer (score 0):

ya, but u need to write `unicode` before string.
e.g.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract aakash4dev{
  string a=unicode"Hello  sɪˈrɪlɪk";
  function get() public view returns(string memory){
    return a;
  }
}
```

writing `string a="Hello "` will give error, as normal string stored in solidity do not support unicode emojis.

read more: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html